# Raising a number to an integral power

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm currently learning Java along with the Stanford online "Programming Methodology" course and, while it is awesome, I do lack any kind of human feedback.

This exercise was to create a method that took a floating-point value x and an integer k and returned x to the power of k. The method needed to also be able to correctly calculate the result when k is negative using the relationship \$x^{-k} = \frac{1}{x^k}\$.

```
/*
 * File: RealPower.java
 * ---------------------
 * This Method takes a floating-point value 'x'
 * and an integer value 'k' and returns 'x to the power
 * of k'. Method is written to correctly calculate
 * even when 'k' is negative.
 * Program displays a table of values generated using
 * the raiseRealToPower method. where x = PI 
 * and y is generated by 'i' variable in 'for' loop.
 * ---------------------
 * coded by Dartias
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class RealPower extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {

        println("This program raises displays PI to the power of -4 through 4.");

/*
 * assigns 'x' the named constant value stored in PI        
 */


        double x = PI;

/*
 * this loop uses the raiseToRealPower method to generate the
 * values for powers of -4 through 0.
 */

        for(int i = -4; i <= 0; i++){

            println(x + " to the power of "+ i + " is " + raiseRealToPower( x, i));
        }

/*
 * this loop uses the raiseToRealPower method to generate the
 * values for powers 1 through 4.
 */

        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){

            println(x + " to the power of "+ i + " is " + raiseRealToPower( x, i));
        }

    }


/*
 * this method calculates x to the power of k.
 * in the event that 'k' is a negative number
 * the method uses the Math.abs method to convert it
 * to a positive number and then uses the formula
 * x(power of -k) = (1/x(power of k)) to ensure the
 * negative exponential powers generate correctly.  
 */

private double raiseRealToPower(double x, int k){

    double total = x;

    if(k >=0){
        for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
            total *= x;
        }} else {
            k = Math.abs(k);
            for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
                total *= x;
            }
            total = (1/total);
        }
    return total;
    }

/*
 * defines the named constant PI and assigns it a value.
 */

private static final double PI = 3.14159265;

}
```

Comment: One hint: you are overcommenting, e.g. "defines the named constant PI and assigns it a value" is just repeating the code in a comment.

Comment: Also, there's excessive whitespace.

Comment: Since you are learning Java, consider an algorithm using [recursion](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/~msmith/cs235/notes/barker/11-recursion-7/235-7-3-recursion.txt). It's way more beautiful than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 7):

Your function fails to calculate \$x^0\$ correctly. I would expect it to return `Double.NaN` when \$x = 0\$, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: [Windows calc is borked!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DVKrc.png)

Comment: Oh this depends very much on who you ask and when you ask them.  In general, I consider \$0^0\$ to be an indeterminate form.  But there are cases where it's convenient to define it as 1.  For example, when dealing with polynomials: $$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$$ which is a bit less annoying to write than: $$p(x) = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x^i$$.

Answer (score 7):

If you are a beginner, thats what you do and look at the results.  It is good.

If this would be a real problem, there are substantially more efficient solutions:  Your solution is linear in x: For each unit in x you make 1 multiplication.   There is however a logarithmic solution possible: In each step, compute the square of the factor of the previous step.    If this factor occurs in the original x, multiply the result with the factor. 
I know this a shortish description, but you want to learn, right?

if it were real I wouldn't call max but look at the sign bit.  If it were real I would also add overflow, or, underflow tests.

Lastly, I would stronger separate the computation from the output display.    Comments are good, but you have overcommented.  The purpose of the comment is to help understand the program, not obscure.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> /*
>  * assigns 'x' the named constant value stored in PI        
>  */
>
> double x = PI;
> ```

Comments should say *why* not *what*. The day you rename `x` to `foo` you're left with this:

> ```
> /*
>  * assigns 'x' the named constant value stored in PI        
>  */
>
> double foo = PI;
> ```

And then 6 months later, `PI` gets boring and now you want `42` instead:

> ```
> /*
>  * assigns 'x' the named constant value stored in PI        
>  */
>
> double foo = 42;
> ```

Comments aren't supposed to be executable:

> ```
> /*
>  * this loop uses the raiseToRealPower method to generate the
>  * values for powers of -4 through 0.
>  */
>
>         for(int i = -4; i <= 0; i++){
>
>             println(x + " to the power of "+ i + " is " + raiseRealToPower( x, i));
>         }
> ```

The maintainer will see what `i` starts and ends at by looking at the `for` loop definition - the comments are just noise that as a maintainer, I'd delete mercilessly.

--

Another thing is that these aren't *comments*, they're *JavaDoc*. This code is heavily abusing JavaDoc. I would have expected this:

> ```
> // assigns 'x' the named constant value stored in PI        
> double foo = 42;
> ```

JavaDocs are good for `public` methods however... but you're being way too verbose:

> ```
> /*
>  * this method calculates x to the power of k.
>  * in the event that 'k' is a negative number
>  * the method uses the Math.abs method to convert it
>  * to a positive number and then uses the formula
>  * x(power of -k) = (1/x(power of k)) to ensure the
>  * negative exponential powers generate correctly.  
>  */
>
> private double raiseRealToPower(double x, int k){
> ```

It's a `private` method... its intent, and that of the parameters, should be clear from the method's signature alone.

---

> ```
> /*
>  * defines the named constant PI and assigns it a value.
>  */
>
> private static final double PI = 3.14159265;
> ```

Java already has some [`Math.PI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) constant ready for you to use. But if you are going to define private fields in your class, it's probably better to put them near the top:

> ```
> public class RealPower extends ConsoleProgram {
>
>     private static final double PI = 3.14159265;
>
>     public void run() {
>
>         ...
>     }
>
>     ...
> }
> ```

Comment: I usually have no issues with Javadocs for `private` methods, since they can serve as "developer notes" and also useful if anyone chooses to generate Javadoc for private methods too... Just a small note that Javadocs for methods/classes will have to start with `/**` on the first line to be properly picked up by the `javadoc` tool. Upvoted anyways. :)

Answer (score 7):

There are already quite a few excellent answers here, so I'll clean up your code with regards to them.

Original:

```
private double raiseRealToPower(double x, int k){

    double total = x;

    if(k >=0){
        for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
            total *= x;
        }} else {
            k = Math.abs(k);
            for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
                total *= x;
            }
            total = (1/total);
        }
    return total;
    }
```

After cleaning up the format:

```
private double raiseRealToPower(double x, int k) {
    double total = x;
    if (k >= 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            total *= x;
        }
    } else {
        k = Math.abs(k);
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            total *= x;
        }
        total = (1/total);
    }
    return total;
}
```

As [200_success's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64332/29611) mentioned, your code won't work for `k = 0`. Also, there's a DRY violation; you repeated a `for` loop.

After fixing some of these issues and condensing the code:

```
private double raiseRealToPower(double x, int k) {
    double total = x;
    if (k == 0) {
        return (x == 0) ? Double.NaN : 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < Math.abs(k); i++) {
        total *= x;
    }
    return (k < 0) ? (1/total) : total;
}
```

If we take a closer look, we can see that there's no need for a specific case where `k = 1` but `x != 0` if we set `total` to 1 and start the loop from 0.

```
private double raiseRealToPower(double x, int k) {
    if (x == 0 && k == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    double total = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(k); i++) {
        total *= x;
    }
    return (k < 0) ? (1/total) : total;
}
```

This is quite concise and clear IMO; you should aim for these two goals in all of your code. :)